# How can I test my browser ignoring Location headers?

Tags: browser, http-headers, location

I want to test a site with my Firefox ignoring `Location:` headers like this example in PHP.

```
header('Location: another-page.php');
```

Is there a plugin available to do this, or any other method?

Would my best bet be surfing the site with Lynx? Does Lynx ignore them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try bringing up the pages with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

It is a command line application that is invoked via:

```
curl http://url
```

cURL does not follow `Location:` headers by default.